# How to add title to each subplot in PLOTLY JS

Tags: javascript, graph, title, plotly.js

just like in subject. 
I read documentation from plotly but i did not found any helpfull information. Maybe someone know how to add title to each plot in PLOTLY JS ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment you can,t set the subplot title directly. 
But you can set subplot title using `annotation text`.

Hear is a [example](https://codepen.io/mdnasirfardoush/pen/gjovjO?editors=1010)

```
    //Set annotations text in layout configuration
annotations: [{
        text: "First subplot",
          font: {
          size: 16,
           color: 'green',
        },
        showarrow: false,
        align: 'center',
        x: 0.13, //position in x domain
        y: 1, //position in y domain
        xref: 'paper',
        yref: 'paper',
      },
        {
          text: "Second subplot",
          font: {
          size: 16,
          color: 'orange',
        },
        showarrow: false,
        align: 'center',
        x: 0.9, //position in x domain
        y: 1,  // position in y domain
        xref: 'paper',
        yref: 'paper',
        }
      ]
```

[Annotation text plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/text-and-annotations/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a feature request on [github](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2746). In this discussion another workaround was posted by nicolaskruchten: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2746#issuecomment-810195118. It's still using annotations but referencing the axes domains. This has the advantage of a proper positioning relative to the subplot and the annotation stays fixed even on zooming.

Defining a domain on the axis you want to position the title (the domain is the "share" of the whole plotly canvas the subplot axis is :

```
    layout: {
      xaxis: { 
        domain: [0,0.48] ,
      },
      xaxis2: {
        domain: [0.52, 1],
      }
     }
```

the annotation itself can reference the domain on this (or both) axis:

```
  annotations: [
    {
      text: "X1 title",
      x: 0,
      xref: "x domain",
    },
    {
      text: "X2/Y2 title",
      x: 0,
      xref: "x2 domain",
    }
  ]
```